# htaccess wildcard redirect to closest match

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have some old links that aren't easily changed (given to 3rd parties), that follow a format like MODEL-VERSION_FILENAME.pdf. An example would be ABCD1234-01a_Product_Info.pdf

They all exist in a folder:
https://example.com/files/ABCD1234-01a_Product_Info.pdf

Occasionally, we change the VERSION part of the filename and delete the old one off the server. Ex: ABCD1234-01a_Product_Info.pdf gets deleted and ABCD1234-01b_Product_Info.pdf (only difference is 01a becomes 01b).

So what ends up happening is the 3rd parties link to the older ABCD1234-01a_Product_Info.pdf (version 01a) file and it's been deleted and get a 404. Ideally, the user should see the newer ABCD1234-01b_Product_Info.pdf (version 01b) instead.

Is there a way to use htaccess to wildcard redirect them to the closest matching file? Or maybe there is just a better way to do this that I'm not thinking of (using a PHP script or something)?

Thank you.

Comment: Please do share your tried htaccess rules file in your question, thank you.

Comment: Do you know what the latest version is? Is this stored somewhere?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Have not tried anything yet, just want to see if this is even possible to do.

Comment: @MrWhite It will vary depending on the model so I was hoping there was a way to match the closest file or something.

Comment: I don't think `MultiViews` can help here, and anything else done purely in .htaccess could probably only "try" a couple of possible specified variations as well. I would set up a PHP script here as fallback (either per rewriting, or as the ErrorDocument 404 for the folder), have that replace the version number part in the originally requested file name with wildcards, and then `glob` the directory using that.